# facebook graph api rate limit for page feeds

Tags: facebook-graph-api, rate-limiting, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

My application collects information about 10,000 Facebook pages to build an experimental data model.

As per my understanding, page access token is meant for page administration and its API limit is restricted to the page it belongs to.

If above is true, then I will have to fallback on the user access token limit which is 200 per hour. I also came across a mention of 600 requests per 600 second in few blogs/SO posts so not sure what's applicable in my case as I am pulling information about publicly available pages not owned by me.

Is there any other way to get a higher limit? I am using the following query -

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/BillGates/feed?limit=100&fields=created_time,updated_time,message,likes.limit(0).summary(total_count),reactions.type(LOVE).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(LOVE),reactions.type(WOW).limit(0).summary(total_count).as(WOW)&access_token=FB_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

Comment: No, there is no way to get those limits increased.

Comment: what is the rationale for this 600 posts limit per year as mentioned here?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.0/page/feed